# How do I change Steam's tray icon?

Tags: themes, steam, panel

[image]

I can't find an option to change Steam's panel icon. It's alright if I'm using a dark theme but I'm using a light theme and it's almost the same color as my panel.

Comment: Wait, what? Are you using a dark or a light theme? The only simple way of doing that is changing the icon theme.

Comment: Changing the icon theme doesn't change that icon.

Comment: Some icon themes sare the same icons, for example "xxx" and "xxx-dark".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every application installed with `dpkg` or `apt-get` has a `*.list` file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` folder. Those files list everything associated with that application, including images. According to `/var/lib/dpkg/info/steam.list`, there is `/usr/share/pixmaps/steam_tray_mono.png` file, which is the icon you wish to change. You could take that image and replace it with another ( of the same size preferably, which on my system is reported as 48x48 pixels ).  Example of that would be a two-step process, like so:

Backup original image first,

```
sudo mv /usr/share/pixmaps/steam_tray_mono.png  /usr/share/pixmaps/steam_tray_mono.png.bak
```

Move in the new one

```
 sudo mv /path/to/new/image.png /usr/share/pixmaps/steam_tray_mono.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you cannot change Steam's menu icon. You can temporarily replace it with another icon, but it will eventually get replaced with whatever Steam wants it to be, during an update.

You should probably contact Steam support to complain that the Steam tray icon does not work well with light themes, and hopefully they will fix it in an update, so it works well on both.